# Clickhouse ALTER MATERIALIZE COLUMN is not available

Tags: clickhouse

`SELECT version()`

21.3.10.1

`ALTER TABLE tmp MATERIALIZE COLUMN s`

Expected one of: INDEX, TTL

Why?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2021.md#clickhouse-release-v2110-2021-10-16

## ClickHouse release v21.10, 2021-10-16

...

Add ALTER TABLE ... MATERIALIZE COLUMN query. #27038 (Vladimir Chebotarev).